# Ongoing Comic Book Grant [Updated June 4 2012]

Tags: discussion, promotional-grant

5 users (aka *The Comics Team*) will get 3 comics a week for one month. The 5 users will be required to create questions/answers in order to be eligible for the following month. Users will be determined by highest rep accrued in a month span.

**Elaborate details!**

- Users interested in receiving comic books will **answer this question with their username**, thus entering themselves for ongoing consideration for the grant. **If at any time you wish to remove yourself from consideration, delete the answer with your name in it.**
- The **Comics Team members who have met their question and answer requirement will be chosen to receive comics for the month.** The remaining spots will be given to new or lapsed users, in order of the highest rep accrued in the previous month (track that [here](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/82/month/scifi)). **5 users will be chosen**.
- **Every Monday of the month**, I will email these 5 users  (aka *The Comics team*) the list of comics being released that week (courtesy of [iFanboy](http://ifanboy.com/comics/)). Each user will **select 3 comics**.
- For expediency and easiness sake, I would prefer to gift comics digitally through [Comixology](http://www.comixology.com/)) when possible. If not, they will be shipped via [Midtown Comics](http://www.midtowncomics.com/) to Team members in the US and [Reed Comics](http://www.reedcomics.com/) to Team members in the UK. **If you do not live in the United States, please provide me with your local online retailer that we can order single issues through.** If an online retailer is not available international team members may have to choose items from their country's Amazon in place of single issues. **Sadly, reimbursements are no longer an option.**
- **Recipients will then have their assigned month to ask or answer a minimum of 7 questions** in the [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics), [marvel-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-comics), [dc-comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-comics) or any other comic publisher tag. Only questions in these tags count. If you notice that a question you are answering is a comic book question but is not tagged properly, tag it. Since it's unlikely that every issue will inspire questions, **any comic book questions you ask or answer during this month count towards your 7**. Writing a blog about comic books counts as asking 3 questions (we need [blog content](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/)).

---

**JUNE 2012 COMICS TEAM/May results**

- [Jack B Nimble](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1148/jack-b-nimble)/6Q+2A, 887 Rep
- [Pureferret](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3804/pureferret)/3Q+7A, 2175 Rep
- [DVK](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/976/dvk)/8Q+6A, 2737 Rep
- [dlanod](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4056/dlanod)/16Q+6A, 2528 Rep
- [System Down](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/887/system-down)

---

The five June recipients will be chosen on **Friday, June 1st, 2012 at 2pm EST/19:00 UTC.** If you are interested in receiving comics in June, please add your name as an answer.

Comment: I'd definitely be interested, but I don't know my eligibility because of the New 52 grant.

Comment: All previous grants get washed away as of...now! Or as of 2012. Bold new year!

Comment: I'd be very interested in this - I'm an incredibly active comics reader, I just need to translate that to activitiy here.

Comment: @IanPugsley Sign up! The grant is launched, and rules are defined!

Comment: I'm wondering, would there be any possibility of reimbursement if I want physical comics, rather than having them shipped?  I've already got my subs set up and a local comic shop I'd like to support, and think we  should encourage that line of behavior for anyone interested (comic shops, bookstores, and LGSs need all the help they can get).

Comment: @IanPugsley Yes, that is doable. If you are selected, you'll have to provide us with the receipts to get reimbursed via Paypal. I agree totally about supporting your local comic shop!

Comment: @BrettWhite incredibly awesome, I'll setup my iFanboy later.

Comment: @BrettWhite: This sounds like if you win, you get the comics, then have that month, after you get your comics, to ask the questions, but my understanding from you is that you have to ask the questions to be eligible.

Comment: @TangoOversway The way it is written in the grant is how the grant is.

Comment: @Brett - why only 4 people for Feb? If you just don't have enough volunteers, I would be up for this (for Feb, or if too late, for March) if top-cow comics are eligible.

Comment: @DVK As of the February selection, only 4 people had stepped up. For March we have those 4 plus Tony Meyer, so if you want to apply go ahead! The more the merrier (although only 5 shall be chosen).

Comment: @BrettWhite - Thx. I already posted some without waiting for the grant :)

Comment: This would be a better link for the tracking: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/82/month/scifi (I can't edit it in because of the presence of the featured tag). The leagues page lets you see the previous month, not just the current one.

Comment: Go Pureferret!!!!!!!

Comment: Has anyone been picked?

Answer (score 2):

TangoOversway

(Should I have done that before I posted my first comic question?)

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested, in comics.

30 Characters later...

Answer (score 0):

I am definitely up for this. http://ifanboy.com/users/IPugsley/

Answer (score 0):

Pureferret.... (And then some)

Answer (score 0):

DVK

Filler: 123456789012345678901234567890

Answer (score 0):

dlanod

dlanoddlanoddlanoddlanod ;)

Answer (score 0):

System Down

Horray for digital comics on Comixology (my new drug)!

Comment: Agreed.  Their 99 cent sales are definitely a great way of getting me hooked.